# Reduce data structure

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach, properties, reduce

I have a data structure which is an array of objects, each object contains an array. I have created a function that returns every object within that sub-array and concatenates them into a new array.

What I want, is to associate one of the properties on each object in the parent array with every object within the child array that is then added to the new array.

To explain in code:

### Original Array

```
var clubData =   [
      { club   : 'Manchester United',
        squad: [
            {name : 'Young'},
            {name : 'Rooney'},
            {name : 'Mata'}
                 ],  
      }
      { club   : 'Chelsea',
        squad: [
            {name : 'Hazard'},
            {name : 'Fabregas'},
            {name : 'Ivanovic'},
                 ]
      }
    ]
```

### New allPlayers Array

Here I've extracted each and every object from the 'squad' variable...

```
var allPlayers = [
        {name : 'Hazard'},
        {name : 'Fabregas'},
        {name : 'Ivanovic'},
        {name : 'Young'},
        {name : 'Rooney'},
        {name : 'Mata'}
    ]
```

JS...

```
allPlayers = clubData.reduce(function(a, c){
                  return a.concat(c.squad);
              }, []);
```

### What I want...

The same, but to add to each object the original `club` property from the original array to each resulting object.

```
var allPlayers2 = [
        {name : 'Hazard'
         club : 'Chelsea' },
        {name : 'Fabregas'
         club : 'Chelsea' },
        {name : 'Ivanovic'
         club : 'Chelsea' },
        {name : 'Young'}
         club : 'Manchester United' },
        {name : 'Rooney'
         club : 'Manchester United' },
        {name : 'Mata'
         club : 'Manchester United' }
     ]
```

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allPlayers = clubData.reduce(function(a, c){
              var squad = c.squad;
              for (var i = 0; i < squad.length; i++) {
                  squad[i].club = c.club;
              }
              return a.concat(squad);
          }, []);
```

Comment: That looks like it could work. Would forEach work as well?

Comment: if you are thinking forEach instead of for loop, yes, it would also work, but its much better with for loop, because we iterate over an array of values, strings. You can google for differences.